# Attributes of attributes in a Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a Rails app with a Contact resource, with address, state, and zip fields. There's also fields for users to enter a phone number. On a form from another website that I'm using for inspiration, users can indicate whether the phone is mobile, home or office, in other words the type of phone number. I'm wondering if it's possible to create fields that accept more information about other fields on a model, or if, in this case, Phone should be a separate model (for example, Contact has_many :phones) and the type of phone number as a regular field on the Phone model.

Because in my app a User has_one Contact, I'd rather keep all the phone related information in the Contact model, rather than have User has_one Contact, and Contact has_many :phones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using another model is an option to achieve this. Another one is to create a Hash storing the phone numbers.

```
class Contact
  attr_accessible :phones
  serialize :phones, Hash
end
```

And then you could store each phone in it's appropriate key, e.g.

```
contact = Contact.new
contact.phones = {home: '1234-1234', work: '1234-5678', mobile: '9876-5432'}
contact.save!
```

And they would be accessible by the phones Hash:

```
contact.phone[:home] # => "1234-1234"
```

By providing the `serialize` command on the model, `ActiveRecord` serializes it in order to store on the database.

So it allows you to store Arrays or Hashes to the database, provided you create a `text` field on its table.

The migration would be:

```
rails g migration add_phones_to_contact phones:text
```

For more about serialization: [api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html)